# Using Full text Search with kotlin-exposed

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to implement a [FULL-TEXT SEARCH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) (PostgreSQL) on kotlin by using kotlin-exposed. I have my queries in raw SQL but cannot write queries containing `to_tsvector()`or `to_tsquery()` in kotlin. I couldn't actually find anything similar anywhere. After a bit of reading, I understood that complex queries could be written as raw SQL [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/118) (i couldn't get it working too) but there is a chance of SQL injection in that. Is there a way to tackle this?

I am not posting any code since what I've tried is just trial and error, actually, the methods are not even available in IDE. Any help is appreciated. My DB is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Have you found the answer? Also, could you provide the code, that does not work?